# Using Soap Creating new Record in Dynamics crm 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to create a new record using soap call but its getting error at GenerateAuthenticattionHeader is undefined.could any references appreciated.

```
function new_record()
{
debugger;
var firstname = "srini";
var lastname = "hsk";
var donotbulkemail = "true";
var address1_stateorprovince = "CHD";
var address1_postalcode = "160036";
var address1_line1 = "#1429/2";
var address1_city = "Chandigarh";
var authenticationHeader = GenerateAuthenticationHeader();

// Prepare the SOAP message.
var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'" +
" xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'" +
" xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>" +
authenticationHeader +
"<soap:Body>" +
"<Create xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices'>" +
"<entity xsi:type='contact'>" +
"<address1_city>" + address1_city + "</address1_city>" +
"<address1_line1>" + address1_line1 + "</address1_line1>" +
"<address1_postalcode>" + address1_postalcode + "</address1_postalcode>" +
"<address1_stateorprovince>" + address1_stateorprovince + "</address1_stateorprovince>" +
"<donotbulkemail>" + donotbulkemail + "</donotbulkemail>" +
"<firstname>" + firstname + "</firstname>" +
"<lastname>" + lastname + "</lastname>" +
"</entity>" +
"</Create>" +
"</soap:Body>" +
"</soap:Envelope>";
// Prepare the xmlHttpObject and send the request.
var xHReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
xHReq.Open("POST", "/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx", false);
xHReq.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Create");
xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);
xHReq.send(xml);
// Capture the result
var resultXml = xHReq.responseXML;

// Check for errors.
var errorCount = resultXml.selectNodes('//error').length;
if (errorCount != 0) {
    var msg = resultXml.selectSingleNode('//description').nodeTypedValue;
    alert(msg);
}
}
```

> GetAuthenticationHeader undefined in dynamics crm 2013

Answer (score 2):

Generally your code looks good with one exception. It is good for CRM 4.0. In case you use CRM 2013 your code would not work. Recheck following articles regarding Creation of records in CRM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx

Provided link demonstrates how to create records using REST. In case you anyway want to use SOAP recheck following article: http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/04/create-requests-in-net-and-jscript-in.html

Comment: getting error on the line GetAuthenticationheader() is Undefined.i posted the code.could you plz clarify me.how to create a record using soap request

Comment: Generally. Your code looks good with one exception. It is good for CRM 4.0. In case you use CRM 2013 your code would not work. Recheck following articles regarding Creation of records in CRM - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx)

Comment: any suggestions how to create a record using soap in dynamics crm 2013above link is not understanding to me.plz gave any suggestion ro code samples

Comment: Provided link demonstrates how to create records using REST. In case you anyway want to use SOAP recheck following article - [http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/04/create-requests-in-net-and-jscript-in.html](http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/04/create-requests-in-net-and-jscript-in.html)

Comment: @AndriiButenko I edited your answer with your comment content because the previous one didn't fit stackoverflow rules (the risk was that someone see your post and delete it along with the comments)